# How to hide file icon when use showLine for antd v4.2.5

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am working with [Antd v 4.2.5 Tree](https://ant.design/components/tree/) and at the bottom of this page the work around for this is available. The same works for [Antd v3.* Tree](https://3x.ant.design/components/tree/) but doesnt for the latest version.

[v3 sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-moon-go9e2) and [v4 codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/883vo47xp8)

Any way to get it working for v4 also. TIA

Comment: I don't really have a solution but an issue already exists on github here: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/23261
As you can see, they seem to be aware of that...

Comment: @Clafou, Thanks for the info. Hopefully it is addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details of the fix in [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-fog-gkn8l?file=/index.js:347-492)

Basically, remove the specifying of class to tree

Like:

```
className="hide-file-icon" // Don't specify
```

And Add:

```
showLine={{ showLeafIcon: false }}
```